# Extend partition into grown volume

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I had an Ubuntu VM which I imported into Amazon AWS. I then increased the volume size from 100GB to 1500GB.

How can I extend the partition to use all of the new space.

```
root@pbx-a:~# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   1.5T  0 disk
├─xvda1 202:1    0  97.4G  0 part /
└─xvda2 202:2    0   2.6G  0 part [SWAP]


root@pbx-a:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     100414960 34551944  61265148  37% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev              497332        4    497328   1% /dev
tmpfs             101604      364    101240   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              508016        0    508016   0% /run/shm
none              102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to resize the actual `xvda1` partition, eg. with `parted`. Because `xvda2` is in the way, you'll need to disable it (`swapoff /dev/xvda2`), then remove it or move it during the re-partitioning process, and re-create it if removed and re-enable swap later if desired. Once `xvda2` is no longer positioned immediately after `xvda1`, `parted` should simply let you resize `xvda1` to fill the free space in between.

As for how to use `parted`, you usually want to start with `print` to show the current state of the partition table. If you want to move `xvda2`, <s>simply run `move 2` and, looking at the numbers from the partition table, input the new start and end positions for partition</s> move has been removed in later versions of `parted`, so just remove partition 2. After this, use `resizepart 1` to resize partition 1 to the desired final size. If you left free space after partition 1, you can recreate `xvda2` by running `mkpart` to create a new partition.

At this point, you should reboot so the partition table gets updated.

After this, assuming the partition on `/dev/xvda1` is ext2, ext3 or ext4, running `resize2fs /dev/xvda1` as root will automatically resize the partition to be as large as possible. For other types of partition live resizing might or might not be possible - for instance, with btrfs you would use `btrfs filesystem resize max /` to live-resize the filesystem mounted at `/` to its maximum available size.

Comment: It is ext4, I tried resizetofs /dev/xvda1. I got resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem is already 25536768 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

Comment: My apologies, it seems I misread your `lsblk` output. You might want to disable swap (`swapoff /dev/xvda2`), delete the partition `xvda2`, resize `xvda1` to desired size, re-create `xvda2` in space you left over for it if necessary, then reboot, *then* run `resize2fs`. `parted` should have all the functionality you need, including resize.

Comment: I have revised my answer based on this.